# Non power of two images with eglCreateImageKHR

Tags: opengl-es, egl

Machine is Freescale iMX53, my program creates many images with a call like this:

```
EGLint attr[] = {
    EGL_WIDTH,            720,
    EGL_HEIGHT,           576,
    EGL_IMAGE_FORMAT_FSL, EGL_FORMAT_YUV_YV12_FSL,
    EGL_NONE
};

img = eglCreateImageKHR(egl_display, EGL_NO_CONTEXT, EGL_NEW_IMAGE_FSL, NULL, attr);
```

Later a call like this gets the details (physical/virtual addresses, stride) of the allocated image:

```
eglQueryImageFSL(egl_display, img, EGL_CLIENTBUFFER_TYPE_FSL, (EGLint *)&info);
```

iMX53 runs EGL 1.4 and OpenGL ES 2.0. It appears to me (by investigating the stride value) that eglCreateImageKHR(...) is capable of allocating image width with a multiple of 32 only, which is absolutely bad in my case. Unfortunately I can't use glTexImage2D and friends due to the performance penalty they cause.

Can I make somehow eglCreateImageKHR(...) avoid using 32-byte multiples, or even force it to use 4/8/16 byte align? 16-byte align would also be sufficient for me. I'm not using Android, just a 2.6.35.4 kernel and OpenGL ES / EGL libraries with a custom linux distro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at my implementation on the Freescale iMX53 and you are right - eglCreateImageKHR() requires the texture dimensions to be multiples of at least 32 pixels (not bytes).  In fact, my code rounds the width up to a multiple of 64.

I believe this is a requirement of the AMD Z430, which is the GPU.  My solution was to just allocate the worst case size of 1920 x 1088 once and use those textures for all video formats, since their EGL does not allow resizing anyway.  Use the texture coordinates to compensate for smaller formats, like this:

```
static GLfloat gafTexCoords[] =
{
    0.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f
};

iTextureWidth = (iOriginalTextureWidth + 63) & ~63;
iTextureHeight = (iOriginalTextureHeight + 31) & ~31;

gafTexCoords[2] = gafTexCoords[4] = (GLfloat)iOriginalTextureWidth / (GLfloat)iTextureWidth;
gafTexCoords[1] = gafTexCoords[3] = (GLfloat)iOriginalTextureHeight / (GLfloat)iTextureHeight;
```

Comment: Thanks. You're right, we're talking about pixels not bytes. The real problem is not the scaling of the generated video frames (it's okay), although the VPU output which appeared to be not a multiple of 32 bytes in stride size, thus being displayed as "garbage" after texturing. But I've found that VPU can be given the exact stride size, so now I'm experimenting with this (in fact, the Y component displays right at the moment).